# Something like iOS Simulator for Android phone or tablets (particularly nexus)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am looking for an Android simulator; something which works similar to iOS Simulator on Mac OS.

I am working on a Mac OS.

Comment: thanks for the downvotes. any reasons?

Comment: @AsadIqbal Probably because "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: To be honest, I looked at the Android emulator but didn't find any intuitive way of launching the simulator; maybe there is none. Maybe there is something similar to running an iOS simulator. For now, I am making a project and running my sample project to open the emulator. Will appreciate any shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an android emulator build into the android SDK.  Go to the [android developer website](http://developer.android.com), and [download the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from there. Use the `android` tool in the `tools` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer said, you have the emulator build into the android SDK. I only want to notice that I am having such a good performance with these emulators [link](http://www.genymotion.com/)